# Google search by file size

Tags: data-request, tool-request, search-engine

How can I sort files found by Google search according to their size or show only results that are larger than x Kilobytes?
For isntance using filetype:mbox to find only large .mbox files.

Comment: you can search gmail by size....try (size:5000000) for greater than 5mb for example. no clue if this works

Comment: I'm asking about google search, not Gmail

Comment: i'm well aware. thats why i said try it

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is not supported. There's no evidence of it in the ["advanced search"](http://www.google.com/advanced_search), nor in the guide to [search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?p=adv_operators&hl=en&rd=1) (which advises against worrying about memorizing all of the operators because you can use the advanced search page.)

Also, the [advanced search help page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/35890?hl=en) lists filters and doesn't include file size.